# Como implementar Inyeccion de Depencia en VB.NET Windows Forms, con UnityContainer?

Tags: vb.net

amigos tengo un sistema en VB.NET, estoy trabajando en pasarlo de DataSet a Dapper, utilizo SQL Server 2022, con VS2022, DevExpress, quiero implementar el patron de repositorio, tengo ciertos formularios que son de consulta los cuales no llevaban un CRUD, a estos les estoy aplicando la tecnologia mencionada, revisando en Google encontre un ejemplo pero en C#, lo he pasado a VB.NET, en este realice lo siguiente :

Tres clases :
marcasxfchaxpsnalRepository
ImarcasxfchaxpsnalRepository
marcasxfchaxpsnalService
marcasxfchaxpsnalVM (Esta es la entidad)

Buscando ayuda encontre recomendaciones para trabajar este uno crear la estructura anterior para llamar el SP, lo segundo me dicen que realice Injeccion de dependencia, me sugieron un nugget UnitContainer, hice los cambios, pero al momento de llamar el UnitContenir me da un error que es el siguiente :

bc32045: function resolve(type as type, name as string , paramarray[overrides] as resolveoverride()) as object no tiene parametros de tipo y por lo tanto, no puede tener argumentos de tipo

Este se me presenta al momento de llamar desde el formulario el service, les dejo mi codigo para ver si me pueden ayudar a mejor mi codigo o mi sistema con mejores practicas.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Public Interface ImarcasxfchaxpsnalRepository

```
Function ObtenerMarcasPorFechaDePersonal(pnIDECIA As Integer, pdFCHINIMCA As DateTime, pdFCHFINMCA As DateTime, idDepartamento As Integer, pnIDEFAB As Integer, pcCODIGOPSN As String) As IEnumerable(Of marcasxfchaxpsnalVM)
```

End Interface

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Imports Dapper

Public Class marcasxfchaxpsnalRepository
Implements ImarcasxfchaxpsnalRepository

```
Private _connectionString As String

''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <param name="connectionString"></param>
Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
    _connectionString = connectionString
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <param name="pnEmpresa"></param>
''' <param name="pdFchInit"></param>
''' <param name="pdFchFin"></param>
''' <param name="idDepartamento"></param>
''' <param name="pnModulo"></param>
''' <param name="pcCodigoEmpleado"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Function ObtenerMarcasPorFechaDePersonal(ByVal pnEmpresa As Integer, pdFchInit As Date, pdFchFin As Date, idDepartamento As Integer, pnModulo As Integer, pcCodigoEmpleado As String) As IEnumerable(Of marcasxfchaxpsnalVM) Implements ImarcasxfchaxpsnalRepository.ObtenerMarcasPorFechaDePersonal

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(_connectionString)

        Dim parameters = New With {
            Key .pnIDECIA = pnEmpresa,
            Key .pdFCHINIMCA = pdFchInit,
            Key .pdFCHFINMCA = pdFchFin,
            Key .pnIDEDPTO = idDepartamento,
            Key .pnIDEFAB = pnModulo,
            Key .pcCODIGOPSN = pcCodigoEmpleado
        }

        Return connection.Query(Of marcasxfchaxpsnalVM)("[MCA].[mpxmarcasxfchaxpsnalLst]", parameters, commandTimeout:=30, commandType:=CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    End Using


End Function
```

End Class

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Dapper

Public Class marcasxfchaxpsnalService

```
''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
Private _connectionString As String
Private ReadOnly _marcasRepository As ImarcasxfchaxpsnalRepository
''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <param name="connectionString"></param>
Public Sub New(connectionString As String, marcaRepository As ImarcasxfchaxpsnalRepository)
    _connectionString = connectionString
    _marcasRepository = marcaRepository
End Sub
''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Function mpxObtenerConsultasMarcas()
    ' Puedes llamar al método del repositorio aquí
    Return _marcasRepository.ObtenerMarcasPorFechaDePersonal(1, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 0, 1, "%")

End Function
```

End Class

Configuro en mi MAIN o modulo principal en VB.NET de la siguiente manera:

```
Public Sub Main()

Dim acdataDirectory As String = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath
Dim anok As DialogResult
Dim acUser As String = String.Empty
Dim acPass As String = String.Empty
Dim acDatabase As String = String.Empty
Dim aoIniFile As axdLibrary.IniFileName = New IniFileName(acdataDirectory & "\cnxapp.ini")
Dim alvalues() As String = aoIniFile.GetKeyNames("Connection")

' Registra tus tipos y sus implementaciones en el contenedor Unity
UnityContainer.RegisterType(Of ImarcasxfchaxpsnalRepository, marcasxfchaxpsnalRepository)()
UnityContainer.RegisterType(Of IProductRepository, ProductRepository)()

'Puedes registrar otras Dependencias aqui
Application.EnableVisualStyles()
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
End Sub
```

El error se me da al llamar desde el formulario, dejo el codigo:

Imports ClaLib_DataAccess
Imports DevExpress
Imports DevExpress.Utils

Comment: porque querrias implementar inyeccion de dependencias en una app de escritorio, cuando te alcanzaria con declarar las clases estaticas??? no entiendo a que apuntas.. por tu codigo, tampoco se entiendo ni como lo aplicas, ni donde.. supongo que ese Unitycontainer las aplica.. pero despues, como sabe el sistema donde inyectar???

Comment: Apunto a lo que entiendo, si supiera como implementar las clases estaticas lo haria a como mencionas, primero trate lo mas facil, pero lo que encontre en la web fue que utilizara esa herramienta o ese Nugget. Lo segundo que me consultas, a como lo dices o trato de hacer es implementar el Unit. No encontre mucha documentacion para VB.NET, si me puedes indicar como trabajar lo que mencionas me dejo de quebrar la cabeza o de inventar la rueda.

Comment: Te daré una opinión. Tu estas usando una multitud de patrones y elementos que lo único que están haciendo es que tu trabajo sea más complicado, ahora tienes que aprender: Inyección de dependencias, Patrón repositorio, Dapper y UnitContenir, y por si fuera poco en VB que es una lengua muerta, y todo eso para mostrar unos datos que vienen de un SP ¿no será mucho?.  .Net tiene su forma de natural de hacer las cosas que funciona de maravilla

Comment: Gracias @Yussef, por tu comentario y tienes razón, pero ya tengo un segundo comentario, pero no tengo ni una posible solución o una mejor idea, nuevamente consulto, si me recomiendas como hacerlo funcionar mejor, agradecido, pero se que no es lo correcto y quiero q funcione mejor. Por eso hago las consultas esto deos DataSet si se dañan es un problema por eso opte por dapper ahora

Comment: Te entiendo, no es que no queramos darte una solución es que no la sabemos, y es por lo mismo que te decía antes, porque también para responder a tu pregunta se necesita de alguien que sepa VB, dapper, DI, UnitContenir, Patrón repositorio. Lo que te puedo decir es como yo lo hago: Yo uso Entity Framework, y para aplicaciones winforms, hago algo parecido a los que dice aquí https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/winforms

Comment: Gracias, @Yussef, lo que pretendo es dejar de utilizar los datos set q fue con lo q inicie en VB.NET, por qué mucho problema me dan y pensé en Dapper, por qué he visto la documentación, ahora amigo acepto sugerencia de como pasarme a otra herramienta o mejorar lo que tengo, esa es mi idea de gente de este foro aprender o mejorar. Revisaré pero considero q EF Core para este sistema que tengo es hacerlo nuevo, pero revisaré y si tienes otra sugerencia es bienvenida, solo quiero dejar de utilizar los DS y que me funcione el sistema óptimamente.